# Create array from SelectedItems after msoFileDialogFilePicker

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, ms-office

Trying to create an array of files that I can later 'cycle through' to pull information from each file (the files are laid out identically / forms in excel).  Receiving '6' Overflow error, suspecting this is an error caused by my Loop?

```
Sub WorkOrderList()
'This compiles an array of Files by picking from the folder
Dim objFileDialog As Office.FileDialog
Dim SelectedFile As Variant
Dim arFiles() As Variant
Dim myCount As Integer
Set objFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With objFileDialog
.AllowMultiSelect = True
.ButtonName = "Select"
.Title = "Work Order Picker"
If (.Show > 0) Then
End If
If (.SelectedItems.Count > 0) Then
For Each SelectedFile In .SelectedItems
Do Until SelectedFile = ""
myCount = myCount + 1
ReDim Preserve arFiles(1 To myCount)
arFiles(myCount) = SelectedFile
Loop
Next SelectedFile
Else
End If
End With
Set objFileDialog = Nothing
End Sub
```

I would expect a resulting array arFiles with each element of the array being the files selected from the msoFileDialogFilePicker.

Comment: You can use `ReDim arFiles(1 To .SelectedItems.Count)` just before you enter the loop.  You know how many items you have, so you can avoid the repeated redim statements inside the loop.

Comment: Your loop is nested incorrectly (indenting it would make it a lot clearer what is going on).  You never update `SelectedFile` inside the `Do Until SelectedFile = ""` loop.

Comment: Tim, When I do this, I get '9' Subscript out of range?

Comment: That's because your loop is still nested incorrectly. If you only resize the array once, you're not increasing it in size until your indexer overflows.  I suggest stepping through this with a debugger - you'll see exactly what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to nest the loops like that to copy them. You get the overflow because you have a `Do` loop that is impossible to exit:

```
        For Each SelectedFile In .SelectedItems
            Do Until SelectedFile = ""      '<-- This will never be true.
                myCount = myCount + 1
                ReDim Preserve arFiles(1 To myCount)
                arFiles(myCount) = SelectedFile
            Loop
        Next SelectedFile
```

This will keep incrementing `myCount` until it overflows. Given that the size of the array is always going to be the same as the number of selected items, I'd suggest using a simple `For` loop instead.  Size the array once ([as @TimWilliams suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54410854/create-array-from-selecteditems-after-msofiledialogfilepicker#comment95632831_54410854)), then just use the indexer on `SelectedItems` to copy them:

```
    myCount = .SelectedItems.Count
    If myCount > 0 Then
        ReDim arFiles(1 To myCount)
        Dim idx As Long
        For idx = 1 To myCount
            arFiles(idx) = .SelectedItems(idx)
        Next
    End If
```

Comment: You're a saint, thank you for getting me out of my own trap!

Comment: Yes, it does return the items in the array as I'd hoped.  Thanks again

Comment: This was really helpful. Thanks.
I went with a mixture of the two. ReDim'd the array to correct size up front. Then used a For Each loop as by all accounts they are faster for stepping through a Collection.

Answer (score 0):

```
With objFileDialog
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .ButtonName = "Select"
    .Title = "Work Order Picker"
    .Show
    If (.SelectedItems.Count > 0) Then
        ReDim Preserve arFiles(1 To .SelectedItems.Count)
        For Each SelectedFile In .SelectedItems
            myCount = myCount + 1
            arFiles(myCount) = SelectedFile
        Next SelectedFile
    End If
End With
```